# How to completely disable classic Bluetooth and BLE in Kubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, gnome, kubuntu, bluetooth

I want out of the IoT for now! Starting a new career as a CEH.

steps I've already taken:

1. followed directions from https://www.howtoinstall.co/en/ubuntu/xenial/bluetooth?action=remove
2. typed `sudo apt-get remove bluetooth`, that seemed to work.
3. typed `sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove bluetooth` which returned `package 'bluetooth' is not installed so is not removed`
4. typed `sudo apt-get purge bluetooth` got same message as previous command
5. typed `sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove bluetooth` got same message as step 3.
6. Connected my classic bluetooth audio adapter to my computer, and according to my GUI (KDE) it acted like it could connect! There was no sound though.
7. I want to be air-gapped. Have I done enough? was my GUI wrong?
8. Also I want out of all BLE networks and haven't found anything online about that yet. help here would be greatly appreciated!
9. Are there any android apps being developed to disable BLE on smartphones too?
   Maybe I'm being paranoid but Armis' white paper has me freaked.

**My Bios is InsydeH20 Setup Utility Rev 3.7 and it won't let me disable Bluetooth**

Comment: Open up your computer and remove the adapter card? Also, the BlueBorne hack issues are already resolved in Ubuntu by a) the kernel was unaffected due to having stack protector enabled, b) a bluez update was made to stop the leaking of the BT MAC address. Removing the GUI control software won't disable the hardware, either.

Comment: Blueborne is not my concern, that was so 1 month ago. It won't be the last set of vulnerabilities to be discovered in classic bluetooth though.

Comment: Is there a way to disable my hardware without removing it? I have a laptop.

Comment: On my system i can turn Bluetooth off in the bios.

Comment: My bios won't give me that option :(

Comment: The _bluetooth_ package is not installed by default. It is an extraneous package that provides some extra plug-ins. You could theoretically remove the _bluez_ package, but the hardware will still be there and powered on. If you really want an airgapped system, you'll need to remove the radio hardware. I also don't get why you keep saying "classic" bluetooth.

Comment: I say classic bluetooth  for disambiguation.  So not to be confused with BLE

Comment: http://www.mt-system.ru/sites/default/files/docs/documents/bluetooth_le_comparison.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Afaik, all the desktop environments in Ubuntu along with many applications have hard dependencies on the presence of Bluetooth software modules. However I don't think there's a reason to worry because of their presence alone since you can disable them trivially in *Control Center → Bluetooth*<sup>1</sup>:

[image: Control Center]
[image: Bluetooth settings]

I have no Bluetooth adapter, so I can't toggle to enable or disable it but you can still see the control in the screenshot.

---

<sup>1</sup> This is in GNOME Control Center. Unity Control Center looks a little different but it too features a Bluetooth section.